# Firefox ignores break-after: page when printing hidden div

Tags: html, css, firefox

In our Vue.js application, we are looping over multiple lists and creating tables to print from each list. We set class "pagebreak" on an empty  after the table content.

CSS:

```
.pagebreak {
/*page-break-after: always;*/
break-after: page;
}
```

I have tried clear:float and other possible solutions I found on stackoverflow but they do not work, like setting the class on the div itself and not an empty  element

The page breaks work in Edge and Chrome

[This is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mL0fpsw1/1/) for reference stripped down to only html/css of three tables:

This still does not work in my FF (version in image)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This property on .print-only{} is problematic : `display: table;`

I guess it works how you want if you use : `break-after: column;` maybe because each .pagebreak is considered as a column of a table.

If you take off `display: table;`, `break-after: page;` seems to work correctly/

Comment: Thank you - it worked in the Fiddle with removing that. Will see how I will have to change to get it to work in the Vue version

Comment: used `display: unset;` for `@media print` so the table shows when printing instead of `display: none;`

Answer (score 0):

I think this property is not supported by Firefox. When check official [MDN Doc for page-after-break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after) and open this page in both browser but it is not working in Firefox. If official page can't break page then May be not support by Firefox.